# Problems getting jQuery click to work on mobile platforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I have looked through many other questions that relate to this, but I cannot seem to find something that works.  I am using Drupal 7 and I am trying to modify a DIV tag so that it closes the Add2Any menu by clicking on it.  It works fine on PC browsers, but I haven't had any luck getting the click to work on mobile.  I understand that mobile browsers don't typically watch for a click event on things outside of anchor tags.  This lead me to wrap an anchor tag around the div I had been using to click and setting the click event off on the anchor being clicked.  This again works on desktop browsers, but nothing on mobile.  I am open to any other suggestions, thank you.

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.cee = {

    attach: function(context, settings){
    $('.a2a_i_a2a').wrap('<a class="share_close_link href="#"></a>');
        $('.share_close_link').on('click', function() {
          $('#a2apage_dropdown').hide();
      });
      }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j4ngoje7/ This is a fiddle of the html and jQuery.  When it is just the fiddle, it works fine on both desktop and mobile browsers, but not within my actual website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem is that I was using what was once the Share tab from AddToAny.  It had issue with me expanding on the functionality and was ignoring my clicks due to my changes being further down the DOM chain.  My solution resulted in prepending an anchor tag to be above the div tags and absolutely positioning with CSS over top of the share tab.  My answer is as follows.

> jQuery('.a2a_menu_inside').prepend('');
>
> > jQuery('body').on('click', '#closer', function() {
> >
> > > jQuery('#a2apage_dropdown').hide();